# How to index special characters in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I'm trying to index *some* special characters, such as `<>$=+-` with Elasticsearch. I am aware of custom analyzers, however I still see no solution to this problem. Ideally, I'd like to use the standard analyzer entirely except that it would include these characters. I haven't been able to find a decent solution for this. I've also looked into ICU, which does not seem to have a solution to this problem either.

Any help would be appreciated.